# How many UI threads we have in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

Can anyone please tell me that How many UI threads we have in Silverlight? I have tried to find out but not getting the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

There is one UI thread, although there is a composition thread that can help out for GPU operations. Hence you'll find all the documentation talks about *the* ui thread, not *a* ui thread.

Source: [wintellect on web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20131230185609/http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jprosise/silverlight-5-s-new-and-improved-threading-architecture)